# prevent Outlook 2013/2016 from displaying empty rows

Tags: html-email

I have a table with placeholder rows for disclaimers. These get populated based on number of disclaimers set in the backend. All looks good in other versions of Outlook but 2013 and 2016. Outlook 2013 & 2016 display empty rows, leaving wide gaps between the disclaimer and whatever is below it when I have only one disclaimer. Anyone knows how to make outlook 2013/2016 collapse these empty cells please?
Table snippet looks like this:

```
<table class="w320" width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

<!--Regular Disclaimers -->
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:top;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" width="18" align="right" valign="top" ><span style="padding:2px;">*</span></td>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" align="left" valign="top"><span style="padding:2;">Amount may change depending on available bonus offer and/or your use of coupons. </span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" width="18" align="right" valign="top"></td>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" align="left" valign="top"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" width="18" align="right" valign="top"></td>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" align="left" valign="top"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" width="18" align="right" valign="top"></td>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" align="left" valign="top"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" width="18" align="right" valign="top"></td>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" align="left" valign="top"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" width="18" align="right" valign="top"></td>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" align="left" valign="top"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" width="18" align="right" valign="top"></td>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" align="left" valign="top"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" width="18" align="right" valign="top"></td>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000" align="left" valign="top"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How is the coupon information added? This seems incomplete.

Comment: It's scripted from the backend and gets added to the rows as they get populated. All the empty rows are placeholder.